# matplotlib.pyplot.plot just gives two nodes without giving the line, why is that?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a line between 2 nodes (x1=130, y1=130) and (x2=202, y2=202)

this code works well

```
coor = np.array([[130,202],[130,202]])
_ = plt.plot(coor[0],coor[1])
```

and I got

[image]

However, the following code coming from the [matplotlib doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html), does not work as stated there

```
plt.plot(130, 130,'g^', 202, 202, 'r^')
```

[image]

which just gives two nodes without giving the line, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in the matplotlib docs, in `plot(x1, y1, 'g^', x2, y2, 'g-')`, `x1`, `y1`, `x2` and `y2` are assumed to be different *data sets*, i.e. arrays consisting of multiple points.

In this case, you'd get a plot of `x1` vs `y1` with green triangles and a green line connecting the points of `x2` vs `y2`.

But you won't have a line connecting `x1:y1` to `x2:y2`.

Also you probably meant to write `plt.plot(130, 130,'g^', 202, 202, 'r-')` (note the minus instead of the `^`).

So e.g. this will work:

```py
plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4],'g^', [5, 6], [7, 8], '^-')
```

[image]